# Why wont salesforce allow mass emails of more than 500 people at once

Tags: email

Salesforce does not allow you to send mass emails to more than 500 people at once. There are third-party tools like ExactTarget that can do this but the problem is that none of these third party solutions are as easy or as integrated as the built in mass email tools are.

What is the reasoning behind this limitation?

Comment: Can you please post this in ideas?This site is for implementation and customization related  queries .

Comment: As @MohithKumar says, [Salesforce Ideas](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaHome?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC) is the place to post this.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that they don't is that they're trying to mitigate their chances of have customers send spam via their mail system.

The more emails a customer is allowed to send the higher the chance they'll use it without properly conforming to anti-spam legislation.

If a salesforce mail server ends up on a spam blacklist that's a *bad* thing as it's going to block internal workflow emails to actual users across multiple org.

One last note: they can raise this limit if you convince the relevant project manager you have a legitimate use that's not well served by a partner. If this is for something that's not marketing blasts you may want to open a case and pursue this.